# Transmitting large data between two spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, inputstream

I have two spring boot services names A and B.

- Service A receives a multipart file (which is huge in size > 100MB - 1GB in size).
- Service A needs to transmit the file to Service B (**problem area**)
- Service B performs some operation on data and return to Service A.
- Calls from A to B is sent using RestTemplate.

**Problem Area**

- Service A doesn't load the whole file in memory, but read from Multipart InputStream in chunks.
- Chunks are sent to B, rather a complete stream.

Is it possible to send the complete InputStream of multipart to service B, so that service A doesn't load the file as well as chunk the file over http/...(any other way)

(One way I had solved it to use fifo on the underlying linux platform and service A is writing continuously on a pipe and Service B is reading) - was looking someway to achieve it with http if possible.

**Background** - I want Service B to be in control of how much chunk they want and not Service A. It is because of the operation Service B perform - service B adds some additional bytes, so that when the reverse operation is performed on next data, it can see these additional bytes to understand how much more chunk should be read.

**UPDATE OF THE GITHUB**
I am not sure where I am getting it wrong? I pasted the complete project - https://github.com/robin-carry/large-data-transfer

The main files on client/server where all logic is below / README.md explains everything I am trying/failing to do...

client/src/main/java/com/lockdown/lazy/client/controller/UploadController.java
server/src/main/java/com/lockdown/lazy/server/controller/OpServiceController.java

Answer (score 0):

Apache Http Client documentation talks about [Request/Response entity streaming](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming) - see if that helps solve your scenario.

Comment: I tried your option and actually `RequestEntity` is really helpful. This is exactly what I was looking, but it isn't working for large files - I am not sure where I am getting it wrong? I pasted the complete project - https://github.com/robin-carry/large-data-transfer 

The main files on client/server where all logic is below / README.md explains everything I am trying/failing to do...

client/src/main/java/com/lockdown/lazy/client/controller/UploadController.java
server/src/main/java/com/lockdown/lazy/server/controller/OpServiceController.java

Answer (score 0):

You can design interface with org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile as argument, then- use it as feign client on sender side and implement it in controller on receiver side